# C++ empty interface destructor in header file

Tags: c++

In C++ I have a header file I.h defining an abstract class (interface) with an empty
virtual destructor:

```
class I
{
  public:

    virtual ~I() {}
};
```

- Question 1: Is the object code for the empty destructor going to be generated in the object file of each .cpp file that includes I.h?
- Question 2: If the answer to question 1 is yes, can this be a problem (same method in different object files)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it will not. Methods defined inside the class definition are automatically `inline`, so no need to worry about it.

Note that a method being marked `inline` and actually be inlined in the binary is different. `inline` is just a marker (a compiler hint at best). Especially with `virtual` functions. Polymorphism is guaranteed to work, regardless of whether the methods are marked `inline` or not.

Comment: Is there a way to have a method defined in the class definition but not inline?

Comment: @Giorgio: No, there's not. It has to be inline to not violate ODR.

Comment: @Giorgio as far as I can recall, the standard says that a method defined inside a class is inline, so I don't think so.

Comment: @Giorgio but note that this doesn't mean it's *inlined*. Read the answer again.

Comment: How does it work with a virtual destructor that is called when a pointer to a subclass is delete-ed? I do not fully understand how this call to the destructor can be inline. Is there some material I can read about this topic?

Comment: @Giorgio don't get too hung up on the inline part. A virtual destructor guarantees calling all destructors in the inheritance chain. That's it. It doesn't matter that it's inline or not.

Comment: What matters to me is where the binary code for the body of the virtual destructor is put and how it is accessed. I do not understand this.

Comment: @Giorgio just look at the binary then. What platform are you coding on?

Comment: Visual Studio 2005. My question is whether the body of the virtual destructor is put in each obj file multiple times. I asked because I thought this was not compiler-specific. Basically: I know that my example is correct, but I do not understand why.

Comment: @Giorgio MSVS has the option to look at the generated binary. So you should do that. The thing is, it depends - how long your destructor is, whether the compiler thinks it can improve performance, your optimization level. Best way to find out is to debug and "go to dissasembly".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11982/discussion-between-giorgio-and-luchian-grigore)